# I want to check the value of two variables at the same time

Tags: php, html

I have two session variables and I am reading the values from the database. Each variable could have two values 0 or 1.

```
 if($approval->num_rows()==0)
            {
                $full=$this->session->userdata('Full_Payment_Type');
                $part=$this->session->userdata('Part_Payment_Type');
                $intf=(int)$full;
                $intp=(int)$part;


                if($this->session->userdata('Full_Payment_Type')){
                    if($intf==1){
                        $data['courses']=$this->Tutor_model-> fetchTutorCourse($tutorId);
                    }else{

                        $data['courses']=$this->Tutor_model-> fetchTutorCourse_2($tutorId);
                    }
                }
                if($this->session->userdata('Part_Payment_Type')){
                    if($intp==1){
                        $data['courses']=$this -> Tutor_model -> fetchTutorCourse($tutorId);
                    }else{
                        $data['courses']=$this -> Tutor_model -> fetchTutorCourse_2($tutorId);
                    }
                }


                $this->load->view('v_tutorPaymentDetails',$data);
    }
```

For example: if `Full_payment_type=1` the courses should have values from `fetchTutorCourse()` 
    AND if `Part_payment_type=0` the courses should have values from `fetchTutorCourse_2()`

I want to get these two values at the same time and the array `$data['courses']` will have two different values based on the result of var1 and var2. I know this logic is wrong because the code will go always with the first if statement. I tried to create `$data['courses2']` for the second variable but the value will be null. Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will make things easier for those trying to help you and increase your chances of quickly getting a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you wants to use and OR statement. As i understand you want to use the value of fetchTutorCourse() if either `$full == 1 OR $part == 1` and use the value of fetchTutorCourse2() if any of these is equal to 0. In that case you would use something like this:

```
if($full == 1 || $part == 1) {
  $data['courses']=$this->Tutor_model-> fetchTutorCourse($tutorId);
} else {
  $data['courses']=$this->Tutor_model-> fetchTutorCourse_2($tutorId);
}
```

Though if both should be true (1) you would instead use:

```
if($full == 1 && $part == 1) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand you have have two session variables that contain 0 or 1.
and if `Full_payment_type=1` you want to call `fetchTutorCourse($tutorId);` and if `Part_payment_type=0` you want to call `fetchTutorCourse_2($tutorId);`

this can be achieved by following

```
if($approval->num_rows()==0){

    $full=$this->session->userdata('Full_Payment_Type');
    $part=$this->session->userdata('Part_Payment_Type');

    //I empty in case if the session is not set for any reason it won't give any warning. for 0 empty will return false.   
    if(!empty($full)){
        $data['courses'][] =$this->Tutor_model-> fetchTutorCourse($tutorId);
    }
    if(!empty($part)){
        $data['courses'][] =$this -> Tutor_model -> fetchTutorCourse_2($tutorId);
    }

    $this->load->view('v_tutorPaymentDetails',$data);
}
```

please try this and let me know if you want to do something else.